# Scrapy ignore settings.py

Tags: scrapy

scrapy ignore my settins.py

my scraper.py

```html
import scrapy



class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.doctolib.de/directory/a']

    def parse(self, response):

        if not response.xpath('//title'):
            yield Request(url=response.url, dont_filter=True)

        if not response.xpath('//lead'):
            yield Request(url=response.url, dont_filter=True)

        for title in response.css('.seo-directory-doctor-link'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::attr(href)').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('li.seo-directory-page > a[rel=next] ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

In the same folder as the Script is placed is a settings.py with the following in it

```html
# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 5
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    # Fix path to this module
    'botcrawler.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 600,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = '/home/user/botcrawler/botcrawler/proxy/list.txt'
```

Why he don't load this file? What i do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

settings.py file should be in parallel of the spiders folder and your scraper.py should be in spiders folder. You can override the existing settings.py file.

Comment: ohh okay where is the spiders fodler located on Ubuntu?

Comment: Run scrapy startproject name. It will create a directory in same path . And you will find everything in it

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your other recent posts it looks like you are struggling to start a scrapy project.  It would be a good idea to read the Scrapy Tutorial [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

In summary, it will describe how to start a scrapy project by using the command `scrapy startproject Blogspider`

This will setup 3 linked folders: Blogspider >> Blogspider >> Spiders

In the second folder will be the `items.py` and `settings.py` files and a couple of other files.  You only really need to edit the `items.py` file.

In the Spiders folder is where you put your spider and it will read the `items.py` and `settings.py` file etc from the prior folder.